# Regex: To split String into Groups

Tags: regex

Minor updates to the string as I did not phrase the problem statement clearly the first time round.

I have a string: `'( 5m 3s ) John: Hi <br> Hello <br>( 6m 2s ) Jane: Hello<br>'`

I am trying to match the string to extract each message as 1 line each.

```
1st group: ( 5m 3s ) John: Hi <br> Hello <br>
2nd group: ( 6m 2s ) Jane: Hello<br>
```

Can someone advice on the regex for this?
This is what I am trying to use currently and I am unable to tell the last break in the regex:

`(.*?).*?:.*?<br>`

Comment: Each programming language has its own dialect for regex. So wich language do you use? Please add an appropiate tag.

Comment: Define the "portions". Are the parentheses part of the "time portion"? Is the colon part of the "name portion"?

Comment: I'm using apex. The parentheses and colon are identifiers as there will be multiple lines with the above and I am trying to manipulate the string using regex to match the pattern.

Comment: Start by reading a primer on regexes. Parentheses have special meaning, they won't just match themselves the way you used them.

Comment: Rephrased the question. Was not stating the problem statement clearly previously.

Answer (score 2):

This Regex pattern matches your 3 groups. The first group is time (Everything between the brackets), second name (after brackets and before colon) and third is the message (after colon).

```
\((.*)\)([^:]*):(.*)
```

For developing regular expressions you can probably use online regex tester, such as https://regex101.com/. Thats very easy and there are explanations for every possible pattern.

Answer (score 0):

parentheses are special regex character, you want to escape them to match them, this way: `\(.*\)`
With `\(.*\)`, you'll match the whole time part.
As for the John part, you can match it starting with a whitespace(`\W`) and ending with the column: `\W.*`:
For the hi, start with column and go on: `:.*`

Just to know, you have only that string or it is a string you want to match in a larger text? Because in that case you need to be carefull as where to stop after the `Hi` part

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! You should take a look at the formatting options in the editor - the asterisks are used as italics marker unless enclosed in backticks, for example. Also, `\s` is the token for whitespace, not `\W` (that matches a non-alphanumeric character).